# Нужна ли запятая перед "как"?

Tags: пунктуация

За таким как за горой будешь.
Волосы черные как смоль.

Answer (score 1):

В этих предложениях всё просто: в первом "как за горой" входит в состав сказуемого "будешь как за горой", поэтому запятая не ставится.  Во втором предложении "черные как смоль" - устойчивое сочетание, запятая перед "как" не ставится.

Валентин, вчера Ларf подсказала, как делать абзац: два пробела. Спасибо ей ещё раз!

Answer (score 0):

Сравнительный оборот с как выделяется запятыми. Не выделяются обороты с как, если они представляют собой устойчивое сочетание. Следовательно, вопрос в том, считать ли обороты "черный как смоль", "за ним, как за горой" устойчивыми. Полного и конечного списка не существует. Я расставила знаки именно так.  ИМХО.

Answer (score 0):

Даже в разных толковых словарях по-разному поставлены знаки препинания ([ссылка тут](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/1031350)). Особенно Ожегов - молодец:  *"Волосы, чёрные как смоль"*. От балды поставил запятую, думая, наверное, что *"черные как смоль"* - это обособленное определение. А вот и нет! Это сказуемое. Поэтому в таком предложении запятую ставить не надо.

---

**А вот в таком, как: *"Черные, как смоль, волосы развивались на ветру"* я бы поставил запятую, так как это явно сравнение**. Мы должны его обособить.

---

Про *"за ним, как за горой"* не нашел никакой информации, поэтому это вряд ли фразеологизм. Следовательно, ставим запятую.

---

P.S. Товарищи, я правильно расставил знаки препинания в выделенном предложении?

---

P.P.S. Как ставить в ответах абзац без этих черточек?

Comment: >А вот в таком, как: "Черные, как смоль, волосы развивались на ветру" я бы поставил запятую, так как это явно сравнение. Мы должны его обособить.       
развЕвались